# how to configure WPS using wpa_supplicant as a external registrar

Tags: wifi, wifi-protected-setup

I want to test Wifi protected setup. I'm using Linux Ubuntu.

I want to test WPS using external registrar. I am using wpa_supplicant for configuring device as external registrar. Please help me how can configure. give me step by step procedure and guide for WPS

Answer (score 1):

You can use wpa_supplicant as WPS External Registrar (ER) to configure a device. The command below starts the ER, IP address is optional.

```
wps_er_start [IP address]
```

Then use the AP configuration from a locally configured network (e.g., from wps_reg command); this does not change the AP's configuration, but prepares a configuration to be used when adding a new device to the AP's network.

```
wps_er_set_config <UUID> <network id>
```

Finally, to configure the device that wants to join the AP

```
wps_er_pin (use CE PIN)
```

[Here's](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/wpa_supplicant_8/+/jb-mr1-dev/wpa_supplicant/README-WPS) some more information about these commands.